# Change button style on press in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'd like the style of a button in my app to change when it is being pressed. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you need it to change while it is being pressed only, and change back when the user is not pressing it? Or do you need to change it when it is touched, and keep the changed state after the touch is stopped?

Comment: To change back when the user is not pressing it.

Comment: This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088496/how-to-change-image-and-text-color-when-clicking-using-react-native/52155810#52155810) worked on me

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use `TouchableHighlight`.

Here an example:

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableHighlight, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function Button() {

  var [ isPress, setIsPress ] = React.useState(false);

  var touchProps = {
    activeOpacity: 1,
    underlayColor: 'blue',                               // <-- "backgroundColor" will be always overwritten by "underlayColor"
    style: isPress ? styles.btnPress : styles.btnNormal, // <-- but you can still apply other style changes
    onHideUnderlay: () => setIsPress(false),
    onShowUnderlay: () => setIsPress(true),
    onPress: () => console.log('HELLO'),                 // <-- "onPress" is apparently required
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableHighlight {...touchProps}>
        <Text>Click here</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  );
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  btnNormal: {
    borderColor: 'blue',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    height: 30,
    width: 100,
  },
  btnPress: {
    borderColor: 'blue',
    borderWidth: 1,
    height: 30,
    width: 100,
  }
});
```

Comment: This is really helpful! And `onHideUnderlay` & `onShowUnderlay` methods are not conflict with `onPress`. This kinda get me confused a little.

Comment: Just a note that `<TouchableHeighlight>` must also contain an `onPress` handler for this to work (as of React Native v0.34)

Comment: Did not know about `onHideUnderlay` & `onShowUnderlay`! Was googling forever to find out how to accomplish something like this. Thank you!

Comment: Using this method, the style changes only after you hold your fingers on the button ... it will not change only on a tap.

Comment: Important to note that `underlayColor` is required along with `activeOpacity={1}` for this to work.

Comment: how did you get the text color to turn white on click?

Answer (score 36):

React Native now provides a new `Pressable` component that can detect various stages of press interactions.
So, in order to change the color(in general any style) of the component, refer below example:

```
<Pressable
  style={({ pressed }) => [{ backgroundColor: pressed ? 'black' : 'white' }, styles.btn ]}>
  {({ pressed }) => (
    <Text style={[{ color: pressed ? 'white' : 'black' }, styles.btnText]}>
      {text}
    </Text>
  )}
</Pressable>
```

**Code breakdown:**

```
style={({ pressed }) => [{ backgroundColor: pressed ? 'black' : 'white' }, styles.btn ]}
```

Here the style prop receives pressed(boolean) that reflects whether `Pressable` is pressed or not and returns an array of styles.

```
{({ pressed }) => (
    <Text style={[{ color: pressed ? 'white' : 'black' }, styles.btnText]}>
      {text}
    </Text>
)}
```

Here the text style too can be modified as the `pressed` is also accessible to the children of `Pressable` component.

Answer (score 17):

Use the prop:

```
underlayColor

<TouchableHighlight style={styles.btn} underlayColor={'gray'} />
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight

Comment: `underlayColor`will be displayed with a slight opacity.  And setting `activeOpacity` to 0 will completely ignore any styles applied to the unpressed state.

Answer (score 2):

This is **Besart Hoxhaj**'s answer in ES6. When i answer this, React Native is 0.34.

```
 import React from "react";
 import { TouchableHighlight, Text, Alert, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

 export default class TouchableButton extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        pressed: false
    };
}
render() {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => {
                // Alert.alert(
                //     `You clicked this button`,
                //     'Hello World！',
                //     [
                //         {text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
                //         {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
                //         {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
                //     ]
                // )
            }}
            style={[
                styles.button,
                this.state.pressed ? { backgroundColor: "green" } : {}
            ]}
            onHideUnderlay={() => {
                this.setState({ pressed: false });
            }}
            onShowUnderlay={() => {
                this.setState({ pressed: true });
            }}
        >
            <Text>Button</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
button: {
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: "blue",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like that :

```
class A extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      onClicked: false
    }
    this.handlerButtonOnClick = this.handlerButtonOnClick.bind(this);
  }
  handlerButtonOnClick(){
    this.setState({
       onClicked: true
    });
  }
  render() {
    var _style;
    if (this.state.onClicked){ // clicked button style
      _style = {
          color: "red"
        }
    }
    else{ // default button style
      _style = {
          color: "blue"
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button
                onClick={this.handlerButtonOnClick}
                style={_style}>Press me !</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you use an external CSS, you can use className in place of style property :

```
render() {
    var _class = "button";
    var _class.concat(this.state.onClicked ? "-pressed" : "-normal") ;
    return (
        <div>
            <button
                onClick={this.handlerButtonOnClick}
                className={_class}>Press me !</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

It doesn't really matter how do you apply your CSS. Keep your eyes on the "handlerButtonOnClick" method.

When the state change, the component is re-rendered ("render" method is called again).

Good luck ;)

Comment: react-native doesn't have a button component. It uses touchableHighlight, touchableNativeFeedback among others.

Comment: the problem is not about react-native or not... the problem is about to understand how & when react apply styles on component. 
The flow is always the same : handleEvent -> handler -> setState -> render.

My answer is about this flow, not about react-native

Comment: Update - React Native added the [`<Button />`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html) component in [version 0.37](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.37.0)