# Can't find variable 'handleClick'

Tags: react-native, events, react-hooks, event-handling, state

I'm trying to change the color of some buttons onClick and getting this error, what can I do?

[image]

after adding const I now get then error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.target.name')
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `const` in front of `handleClick` on line 44.

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
  //
}
```

Comment: I'm now getting the error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.target.name'), just to clarify I'm copying this code from a solution I saw on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665021/how-to-change-color-of-button-on-press-in-react-native

Answer (score -1):

I think it is better for you to pass your variable instead of using default event value in `handleClick()`.

```
onPress={()=>{
  this.handleClick("YOUR_VALUE");
}}
```

And you can create your own `handleClick()` like this.

```
handleClick = (data) =>{
  console.log(data); // <- should output "YOUR_VALUE"
}
```